Add WAF (Imperva) using together with F5 load balancer, but user cannot pass to any menu after access to main screen
We didn't change coding of Web application but before WAF adding, we able to access any menu via F5 normally.
Before Structure
Client -> F5 load balancer (using iRule) -> Destination server
Result: normal
After Structure
Client -> F5 load balancer (using iRule) -> WAF -> Destination server
Result: able access to main screen but can't transition to any page. (Error internal 500)
Coding to transition menu, it needs to get menu ID by session ID (Ex. ViewHistory:=ScreenA, ScreenB, ScreenC;) and it will transfer to next page (ScreenC) but Value of ScreenB is disappear so we cannot access to SreeenC.
F5 changing
HTTP profile : http -> http-xff
So, we would like to know what item should additional setting on WAF (Imperva)? or what should we check?
